# Trouble using watershed segmentation in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a trouble in segmenting the soil grains shown in the image using this algorithm however it included all particles as one object and calculate its area but this is not my desire as I would like to segment the particles each one individually so what can I modify on the following algorithm to enhance its performance in detecting each grain individually .

and the second image is the result of using this algorithm.

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage

# Load in image, convert to gray scale, and Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('sample64pxfor1mm.jpg')
image = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,15,75,75)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
image = cv2.morphologyEx(image,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Compute Euclidean distance from every binary pixel
# to the nearest zero pixel then find peaks
distance_map = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
local_max = peak_local_max(distance_map, indices=False, min_distance=20, labels=thresh)

# Perform connected component analysis then apply Watershed
markers = ndimage.label(local_max, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-distance_map, markers, mask=thresh)

# Iterate through unique labels
n = 0
total_area = []
for label in np.unique(labels):
    if label == 0:
        continue

    # Create a mask
    mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
    mask[labels == label] = 255

    # Find contours and determine contour area
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    total_area.append(area)
    n+=1
    print('Grain number' , ' of number ' , n , ' has area = ', area)
    # total_area += area
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Take a look at your distance transformation and the acquired markers. The threshold is probably too low and you get only 1 coherent component for all of your objects.

Comment: @TA so could you help me by the correct threshold value I can use in that case to avoid such error